# Clarifications on Python tuple unpacking

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, iterable-unpacking

It's understood that unpacking of a tuple can happen only between tuples/list
so

```
x,*y = (1,2,3,4)
```

is valid. However, if we try to do the unpacking on a single variable

```
*x = (1,2,3,4,5)
```

we get an error as x is not a list/tuple hence unpacking cannot occur. If that is the case then
how can we use *args to have multiple parameters in function

```
def max(* args):
  for x in args:
    print(x)
```

So here if I call max(1,2,3,4). Shouldn't we get an error coz *args is not a tuple therefore we can't do unpacking?

Comment: I think the short answer is that iterable unpacking and star-args have similar syntax since they're similar processes, but they're different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The catch is that the brackets of a **parameter list** always enclose a tuple.
They are brackets you **could not omit**. So they are not mixed up with operator-priority-brackets

By the way, fun fact:
write (NOTE THE COMMA AFTER THE x)

```
*x, = (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Then it works, just like you would neet to add a comma in a bracket to make it a tuple.
like (1) is no tuple, but (1,) is

Comment: yes then it becomes a tuple but when we use *args in function max( *args) where I pass max(1,2,3,4,5); I am passing the tuple to *args = 1,2,3,4,5 which should cause an error right

Comment: Ah, yes, I later understood your point. But look at the edit: It is all about knowing that it IS a list. And function parameters are. You could see it like operator precedence: with *x= the asterisk is evaluated before the right operand. But in the function, the asterisk is evaluated after the function brackets, but before the function is called.

Comment: Well, it actually sees that it is a function. And when the function is CALLED, he sees the parameters as a list, no matter how many of them are there. Distributing them to the parameters of the function is just the next step. Wait! Note that "before the function is called" in my last comment was nonsense.